# QR Generator in Objective-c iOS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, qr-code

I wanted to implement a QR encoder in an iOS application. I have found a solution for this..

[QR Encoder for iPhone](https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C)

However, this is using a C++ complier and wanted a better solution.

I found this:

[Objective-C QR Encoder](https://github.com/lightforce/qrcode)

However, the programme developed this for the OS X not the iOS.

Is the anyone out there that might have a working solution?

Comment: Haha typing error. Sorry

Comment: What could possibly be better than C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE THIS:
https://github.com/angrauel/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C (UPDATED FOR IOS 6)

If you get an error when putting into device:

Go to  Build Settings -> Architectures
then remove the default values "`Standard (armv7, armv7s)`" and add two new values: "`armv6`"; "`armv7`".

This should fix all problems.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7 provide built in classes for QR code generation
https://github.com/shu223/iOS7-Sampler

Answer (score 1):

I recently evaluated different Barcode Encoder SDKs to generate EAN-13, DataMatrix, and Interleaved 2of5 barcodes in an iPhone App. These are the ones I could find:

OnBarcode
http://www.onbarcode.com
Commercial, binary library (no armv64 support)

Zint
http://sourceforge.net/projects/zint/
GPL-licensed, C library
Best API of the SDKs, but the license makes it unsuited for close-sourced iPhone Apps

Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes
https://github.com/netshade/Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes
BSD-licensed, Objective-C library
No ARC-support, no DataMatrix encoder

RSBarcodes
https://github.com/yeahdongcn/RSBarcodes
MIT-licensed, Objective-C library
No DataMatrix and Interleaved2of5 encoders

iOS-QR-Code-Encoder
https://github.com/moqod/iOS-QR-Code-Encoder
MIT-licensed, Objective-C library
Only supports QR-Codes

QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C
https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C
Apache-licensed, Objective-C/C++ library
Only supports QR-Codes

libdmtx
http://www.libdmtx.org
Simplified BSD-licensed, C library (Cocoa-Wrapper available)
Only supports DataMatrix

Answer (score 0):

You could use zint http://sourceforge.net/projects/zint/ 
It is written in C and you can just use it in Objective C.

Comment: Be aware that Zint is GPL licensed, which requires you to release the source code of your app.